# how do i use the user given char or string to create an object with that name?

Tags: java

```
package simplebanking;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class banker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y;
        String c;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("enter your option           ");
        System.out.println("1 to create account");
        System.out.println("2 to existing account          ");
        y = s.nextInt();
        if (y == 1) {
            c = s.next();
            i++;
            Accounts(c) = new Accounts();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What the question this is not the way to ask question in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Accounts` object?

Answer (score 7):

This is not how you do things in Java. There are no dynamic variables in Java. Java variables have to be declared in the source code.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you should probably use a Map. For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> n = new HashMap<String, Accounts>();
n.put(c, new Accounts());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a name field on an `Account`.

```
public class Account{

    private String name;

    public Account(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

With an object definition like this you could set the name of a new account like so:

```
Account account = new Account(c);
```

or you could do this to change an existing account

```
account.setName(c);
```

If you would like to know the name of the account you are working with currently, you could use  the `getter` method as below.

```
account.getName();
System.out.println(account.getName());
String currentName = account.getName();
```